# Last month average constant in Power-Bi

Tags: powerbi, average

I am working in Power-Bi desktop. I need to compute a constant measure (same for all rows) that indicates me the daily average of the amounts stored in a column named "Values" considering the last month as window. The distinct-count for the days of the last month has to exclude the last two days of the week. The window has to start Today() - [DELTA], where DELTA is a constant number of days.

An example below (which is rolling, not constant, and does not include DELTA):

```
dailyAverageValue = 
var nobs = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(TABLE[DATE]), PREVIOUSMONTH(TABLE[DATE]), TABLE[WEEK_DAY_NO] <> 6, TABLE[WEEK_DAY_NO] <> 7)
var summ = CALCULATE(SUM(TABLE[VALUES], PREVIOUSMONTH(TABLE[DATE]))
return summ/nobs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dailyAverageValue = 
var nobs = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(TABLE[DATE]), DATESINPERIOD(TABLE[DATE], TODAY() - [DELTA], -[WINDOW], DAY))
var summ = CALCULATE(SUM(TABLE[VALUES]), DATESINPERIOD(TABLE[DATE], TODAY() - [DELTA], -[WINDOW], DAY))
return summ/nobs
```